XCode project giving build error saying Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), Xcode 16.2, Mac OS Sonoma
This error started to show up all of a sudden out of no where. I have tried all the usual steps like Clean build, removing DerivedData folder, deleted and reinstalled Xcode etc but no luck. Here is the details of the error when selected Reveal in Log (mainly several missing *.o files):
ld: multiple errors: file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxxxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LogFileManager.o in '/Users...
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I have tried all the usual steps like Clean build, removing DerivedData folder, deleted and reinstalled Xcode etc but no luck.
